# C# Windows Forms Chamando um Form neto dentro de um panel no form Avô a partir do Form Pai

Tags: c#

Tenho 3 formulários, Principal, produto e detalhes. No form principal tenho um menu lateral e um panel chamado pnlContent. Neste menu tenho um botão que preenche o pnlContent com o form produto. Dentro do form produto tenho outro botão que preenche o pnlContent com o form Detalhes mas não exibe. Poderiam me ajudar?

(Form Principal)Chamada ao form produto:

```
    private void btnProduto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmProduto frm = new frmProduto
        {
            TopLevel = false,
            AutoScroll = true,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };

        this.pnlContent.Controls.Clear();
        this.pnlContent.Controls.Add(frm);
        frm.Show();
    }
```

(Form Produto)Chamada ao form detalhes:

```
    private void btnDetalhes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        frmDetalhes Detalhes = new frmDetalhes
        {
            TopLevel = false,
            AutoScroll = true,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };

        frmPrincipal Principal = new frmPrincipal();
        Principal.pnlContent.Controls.Clear();
        Principal.pnlContent.Refresh();
        Principal.pnlContent.Controls.Add(Detalhes);

        Detalhes.Show();
        Principal.Refresh();   
        Principal.pnlContent.Refresh();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, você carrega o form de produto no `pnlContent` do main e ao e a partir do produto você quer substituir o conteúdo do `pnlContent` o form de detalhes desse produto?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de instanciar novamente o frmPrincipal, você pode acessá-lo pelo `Parent` e localizar o controle do painel.

```
var Principal = this.ParentForm;
var pnlContentPrincipal = Principal.Controls.Find("pnlContent", true).FirstOrDefault(); 
    pnlContentPrincipal.Controls.Clear();
    pnlContentPrincipal.Refresh();
    pnlContentPrincipal.Controls.Add(Detalhes);

    Detalhes.Show();

    Principal.Refresh();
    pnlContentPrincipal.Refresh();
    this.Close();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Leandro Angelo, deu certo.