# Como mudar o valor de um textbox por outro form? c#

Tags: c#

tenho dois formulários: 'Vendas' e 'produtosDaVenda'

e uma variável geral que está nos codigos como Unique_Home.Program.vendas.preco:

```
public static class vendas
    {
       

        public static string preco { set; get; }

    }
```

no formulário 'vendas' tenho essa função:

```
public void getValor()
{
  TXTvalor.Text = Unique_Home.Program.vendas.preco; //TXTvalor do form 'vendas'
}
```

essa função atualiza o texto da textbox para o valor da variavel

No formulario 'produtosDaVenda' quero chamar essa função e estou usando o seguinte codigo:

```
private void BTNok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Unique_Home.Program.vendas.preco = TXTvalor.Text; //TXTvalor do form 'produtosDaVenda'

        foreach (Vendas oForm1 in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Vendas>())
        {
            oForm1.getValor();
        }

        this.Hide();
        
    }
```

Porém, quando clico nesse botão é me apresentado esse erro:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operação entre threads inválida: controle 'TXTvalor' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.'

pelo que entendi, não posso chamar a função de outro form. Teria algum jeito de permitir isso? Ou alguma outra forma de atualizar o valor do texbox do 'vendas' via um botao no 'produtosDaVenda'

OBS: o form 'vendas' fica aberto a todo momento, enquanto o form 'produtosDaVenda' abre via um botão no form 'vendas'. Esse é o codigo do botão, por via das duvidas:

```
private void BTNproduto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

            Unique_Home.Program.vendas.preco = TXTvalor.Text;

            trocarform = new Thread(abrirform);
            trocarform.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            trocarform.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa resposta e veja se você não consegue uma abordagem semelhante
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361898/c-windows-forms-chamando-um-form-neto-dentro-de-um-panel-no-form-av%c3%b4-a-partir-d/361929#361929

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando modificar um controle de uma thread que não é a que ele pertence, tente alterar da seguinte forma:

```
private void BTNok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
  {
      Unique_Home.Program.vendas.preco = TXTvalor.Text;
    
      foreach (Vendas oForm1 in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Vendas>())
      {
              oForm1.getValor();
      }
    
       this.Hide();
   });
 }
```